# How can I get pyodbc to return correct values from an old MS Access database

Tags: python, ms-access, ubuntu, pyodbc

I am running 64-bit Ubuntu 11.0, 64 bit python 2.7.2, and pyodbc 3.0.3.

I am trying to retrieve data from an old access database (I think it's 97 but not 100% sure) residing on a network windows machine.

I run the following select, and the results are shown:

```
select id, firstname, lastname from customer where id < 5
```

*(id is of type  "Counter" and firstname and lastname are varchar)*

**From python, pyodbc on Ubuntu (something wrong here)**:

```
(16973874, 'Candance\x00\x00', 'Mattingly\x00\x00')
(16973875, 'Anthony & Ana Marie\x00\x00', 'Cushing\x00&')
(16973876, 'Sharon\x00\x00', 'Brown\x00\x00')
```

**From isql on Ubuntu (good results) (reformatted slightly)**:

```
| 2 | Candance             | Mattingly  |
| 3 | Anthony & Ana Marie  | Cushing    |
| 4 | Sharon               | Brown
```

**From python, pyodbc on Windows 7, 64bit (good results)**:

```
(2, u'Candance', u'Mattingly')
(3, u'Anthony & Ana Marie', u'Cushing')
(4, u'Sharon', u'Brown')
```

---

My odbc.ini looks similar to this:

```
[MSACCESS]
Description             = Old MS Access Database 
Driver                  = /usr/lib/libmdbodbc.so.0
Database                = [path to mounted drive].mdb
```

***Basically, pyodbc is returning incorrect results (or interpreting them incorrectly) on Ubuntu. I'd appreciate any helpful suggestions to fix this.***

- I've tried many variations of adding "client charset = XXX", but they didn't seem to have any effect.
- note that from pyodbc on Ubuntu, the "id" column being returned is 16973872 too high, and the varchar columns seem to end in semi-random bytes (many are not \x00)

Comment: This sounds similar to http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/issues/detail?id=56&q=access.  Perhaps you should should add to the bug report or open a new one.

Comment: @Steven: Interesting...looks somewhat similar - difference is that pyodbc works fine for me on Windows (which is what this bug report is for).  It just isn't working the same under Linux.